# Unity3D GetComponent Failing On Component Known To Exist?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, I'm firing a ray at my object. It's returning the object fine. It hits every debug.log but the last. I'm not sure why it would be behaving like this.

```
private void EventDispatcher_RayHitEvent(WeaponRayHitEventArgs args)
{
    Debug.Log("Dispatching Ray Hit Event..");
    m_ProcessedDamage = 
        Mathf.Abs(m_BaseEnergyRayDamage - args.m_RaycastHit.distance) / Mathf.PI;
    if(args.m_RaycastHit.collider.gameObject != null)
    {
        m_CurrentRayHitObject = args.m_RaycastHit.collider.gameObject;
        Debug.Log("Collision Detected..");

        if (m_CurrentRayHitObject.GetComponent<PlayerState>() != null)
            Debug.Log("Player State Detected!");
    }
}
```

The same logic works perfectly fine upon detecting collision, just not ray hits..

```
void CheckCollisionForPlayerState()
{
    if (m_Collision.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerState>() != null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Object With Player State Hit!");
        m_Collision.collider.gameObject.GetComponent
            <PlayerState>().Damage(m_ProjectileBaseDamage * m_ProjectileBaseDamage);
    }
}
```

The component --definitely-- exists.

```
        if (GetCurrentWeapon().GetOwnEmission() == BaseMaterialWeapon.EmissionType.Beam &&
            Physics.Raycast(transform.position + m_ForwardVector, m_ForwardVector, out m_RaycastHit))
        {
            EventDispatcher.InvokeRayHit(new WeaponRayHitEventArgs(m_RaycastHit));
            Debug.Log(string.Format("Object Hit With Weapon Ray: ({0})", m_RaycastHit.collider.gameObject.name));
        }
```

Comment: Please learn simple ways to troubleshoot your code. Print the name of the GameObject then select it from the Hierarchy tab and check if it has `PlayerState` attached to it.  Replace ` Debug.Log("Collision Detected..");` **with** ` Debug.Log("Collision Detected: "+m_CurrentRayHitObject .name);` . Also, you can even select the hit GameObject from script with `Selection.activeGameObject=m_CurrentRayHitObject `. This will be helpful to you in the future.

Comment: @Programmer: Even easier write Debug.Log("My message..."*, this*); Then you can click at the log message in console and Unity does an editor ping directly to the hierarchy view

Comment: @Kay That too should it. I've been wondering what extra parameter is used for.  In this case, it looks like it should be `Debug.Log("My message...", m_CurrentRayHitObject );`